# ¿Cómo parar y arrancar contenedores Docker de forma automática?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, crontab

Tengo una máquina Debian con Docker y varios contenedores corriendo. Necesito que dos de estos contenedores arranquen de lunes a viernes a una determinada hora y se detengan a otra hora.

Había creado dos scripts para hacer esto mismo, este es el que he probado (y funciona si lo ejecuto manualmente) para el arranque:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/containers/traefik/
docker-compose start handbrake
docker-compose start firefox
```

El otro fichero es similar pero en lugar de *docker-compose start* pone *docker-compose stop*.

Ambos ficheros tienen permiso de ejecución y, si los lanzo de forma manual, funcionan perfectamente. El problema es a la hora de meterlos en el crontab. Lo tengo así:

```
00 14 * * 1,2,3,4,5 /opt/containers/scripts/arranca_cont.sh
30 05 * * 1,2,3,4,5 /opt/containers/scripts/para_cont.sh
```

Con eso no hace nada. Ni se detienen ni arrancan y estoy algo perdido con este tema.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Qué falta?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tengo la sospecha de tienes un problema con la variable `PATH`, ya que `cron` ejecuta el script con un `PATH` no necesariamente igual al que usas cuando estás en la terminal.

En caso de ser cierto, al hacer `docker <etc>`, la shell que ejecuta ese programa no encontraría su localización, puesto que la variable definida por defecto por el programa `cron`, es `PATH="/usr/bin:/bin"`.

Tal vez tu ejecutable de `docker` no se encuentre dentro de alguno de estos directorios.

Por esto, te sugeriría que dentro de tus scripts, **definas la variable `PATH` de forma que puedas asegurar que dentro de esta varible se encuentra la ruta del folder que contiene los comandos de `docker`**. Sólo un ejemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH='/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin'
```

En mi caso, el programa `docker` se encuentra dentro del folder `/usr/bin/`. Lo puedes saber por el resultado de esto:

```
$ dirname $(command -v docker)
/usr/bin
```

Otra formas que se me ocurren de hacerlo son:

1. Con `echo $PATH`, muestra el contenido de la variable `PATH` de la consola del usuario que normalmente usas, luego copia y pega esto casi al inicio tu script: `export PATH='<el resultado el echo>'`
2. En lugar de hacer lo anterior, tan sólo carga los archivos de configuración de tu consola al inicio de tu script. Por ejemplo, si usas `bash`: `. /home/<tu usuario>/.bashrc`. Si usas `zsh`, entonces será el archivo `.zshrc`, etc.

En caso de que esto no te funcione, investiga revisando los registros del sistema referentes al programa `cron`:

```
$ grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Gracias. Voy a hacer lo que comentas de la variable PATH y compruebo a ver si está ahí el problema.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola de nuevo. Probé el comando "echo $PATH" y, añadiendo el resultado a mis scripts tal y como comentabas ha funcionado.

Muchas gracias.