# Obtengo un resultado distinto en la consola al obtenido en crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, cron, crontab

He montado un servidor Nextcloud y necesito saber en todo momento mi ip.

Cuando ejecuto este script en consola me funciona bien. Pero con crontab no funciona. ¿Hay algún error?

Por cierto, ejecuto el archivo `crontab` como un usuario logeado y no como super usuario. ¿Tiene algo que ver? He probado de las dos formas y no hay manera.

Mi línea en el `crontab` es la siguiente:
Abro un terminal y escribo:

```
crontab -e
```

Luego en mi crontab tengo lo siguiente:

```
0 * * * *  sh /usr/local/bin/tarea.sh
```

Debería ejecutarse cada hora. El hecho es que cambio la ip en mi fichero para ver si funciona y nada. ¿Cuál es el problema?

Sólo hay tres variables de las cuales una se lee desde el fichero llamado "ip.txt". Que es donde guardo mi dirección de IP.

```
#! /bin/bash

vieja_ip=$(cat ip.txt)              #Leo ip del fichero
nueva_ip=$(curl icanhazip.com)      #Consulto ip
fecha=$(date)                       #Guardo fecha y hora

if test "$nueva_ip" != "$vieja_ip" ; then

    #Guardamos la nueva ip en el fichero
    printf "$nueva_ip" > ip.txt

    #Añadimos la ip y la fecha al histórico de cambios
    printf "$fecha $nueva_ip" >> historico.txt
    
    #Enviamos la nueva ip
    printf "$nueva_ip" | msmtp correo@servidor.com
    exit 0
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Que titulo me sugieres como mas adecuado?

Comment: cron tiene muy pocas variables y por tanto no puede asumirse casi nada. Por ejemplo, en lugar de llamarlo con `sh script.sh`, sería bueno hacerlo con `/bin/sh script.sh` o lo que sea que salga cuando haces `which sh`. Después, ¿tiene cron permisos de ejecución de este script? En cuanto a los ficheros que tratas en el script, ¿en qué ruta están? Porque lo mismo no los encuentra. Para ver si cron está funcionando puedes por ejemplo crear un script que haga `touch /tmp/prueba` y lanzarlo. Si crea un fichero, pues esa parte ya la tienes bien.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Probando touch....

Comment: Los tres ficheros: tarea.sh (com permisos de ejecucción), ip.txt (RW), historico.txt (RW) están en el mismo directorio /usr/local/bin/

Comment: pero la ruta al ejecutarse no es relativa al directorio donde está el script, sino a desde dónde ejecuta cron. Por ello, añade mejor la ruta absoluta de los ficheros

Comment: Muy buena observación. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tú problema es uno muy común, y es que asumes varias cosas:

1. Los comandos que corras en tu terminal podrán ser localizados por el demonio `crond`
2. El directorio de ejecución de `cron` es el mismo que en el que lo corres externamente

Puedes guiarte con [esta pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/412104/c%C3%B3mo-parar-y-arrancar-contenedores-docker-de-forma-autom%C3%A1tica/412105#412105).

En resumen, cuando mandes a llamar tu script, antes dale permisos de ejecución:

```
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/tarea.sh
```

Y en tu archivo `crontab` llamalo como si fuera un script más:

```
0 * * * *  /usr/local/bin/tarea.sh
```

Se correrá por defecto como si fuera un script de `bash` por el *shebang* que está dentro de tu script:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

Dentro del tu script, declara un `PATH` semejante al de tu entorno de ejecución cotidiano.

Esto lo haces poniendo el resultado de la variable `PATH` en tu ambiente, pero dentro del script. En mi caso:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Entonces, pon esto en el incio de tu script:

```
...
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
...
```

Como te sugirió @fedorqui en los comentarios: **usa rutas absolutas a tus archivos**:

```
...
vieja_ip=$(cat /ruta/completa/a/ip.txt)
...
printf "$fecha $nueva_ip" >> /ruta/completa/a/historico.txt
...
```

Esto último es para evitar ambigüedad, sin embargo, puedes usar otros trucos como:

1. En el crontab, cambia a la carpeta donde tiene tu script y luego ejecútalo:

   ```
   0 * * * * cd /ruta/de/script/ && ./script.sh
   ```
2. Al inicio de tu script, haz un `cd` a donde tengas tus archivos:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   export PATH=<el PATH completo que quieras>
   cd /ruta/donde/estén/los archivos
   ...
   ```

Yo preferiría las rutas absolutas.

### Explicación rápida

Esto se resuelve apelado rápidamente al manual de `crontab(5)`, en el cual se establece que:

1. La variable SHELL es por defecto `/bin/sh`, osea, `dash`: una shell bastante primitiva.
2. El *current working directory*, osea, la variable `CWD`, será la definida por el archivo `/etc/passwd` que coincida con el dueño del archivo crontab. Por ejemplo, la carpeta home del usuario al que le pertenezca el archivo `crontab`, ej., `/home/john`.
3. La variable `PATH` está definida como `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`.

Todas estas variables se pueden modificar dentro del script o dentro del archivo `crontab`.

Comment: fedorqui, gracias por tu observación. No hay que dar nada por sentado. Cierto lo de las rutas.

Comment: Cuauhtli, gracias por tu respuesta. Acabo de realizar los cambios que me sugieres. Gracias tambien por la corrección semantica del post. Tomo nota para proximas consultas.

Comment: Gracias a ambos (Fedorqui & Cuauhtli). Teniais razón. Con rutas absolutas todo  funciona de maravilla.